# Entity Framework version 6.1.3 not getting open

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am building an empty MVC application using .net 4.5 framework VS 2012. Then I add entity framework version 6.1.3. After adding I right click on the models folder to add a new entity model. It opens the entity data model wizard where I am selecting "Generate from database". Then it is taking me to choose your data connection , but after a while its automatically closes. I don't know where's the problem is exactly. In web.config file I also changed the entity framework version from 6.0.0.0 to 6.1.3.0 , still it is getting close and not allow me to select my database. I tried EF version 4.0 and 5 as well but the same problem . I have one existing application on VS 2012 with EF version 4.4.0 , where some databases are already there. I have tried adding one more database there and it is adding there. then why not adding on my new application having the same configurations. What would be the problem ? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the answer after working around it for hours. what we need to do is , Go into view->Server Explorer and remove any "Data Connections". Then this worked again.